# Jquery Mobile not passing hiddenfield value?

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, mobile

I am using jQuery Mobile script on my mobile website. I am not much familiar with JavaScript.

There are two website have same code & files.

- http://m.suyes.co/ (with jQuery Mobile)
- http://www.suyes.co/   (without jQuery Mobile)

I used this form to get value

```
<form class="dca-box" action="domain.php" method="post" name="form_domain_avail" id="homepageDomainSearch">
  <input type="hidden" value="check_availability" name="action"> 
  <input type="hidden" name="showrelated" value="true">
  <input data-role="none" type="text" maxlength="65" id="field_domains-input" class="domains-input optionalField" name="txtDomainName" value="Buy a Domain name..."  onkeydown="remove_error_msg();" /> 
  <button data-role="none" onclick="return check_domain_name();" id="search_for_domains_id" type="submit">Search</button>
</form>
```

On my desktop website this working well, but it's only loading page in mobile site.

Comment: add `data-ajax="false"` to form.

Comment: thanks Omar, its work & passing value but loading gif not showing ? why

Comment: because you've disabled Ajax. The result page will be loaded without jQM's Ajax navigation. Use `$.ajax()` methods to communicate with server if you want to keep jQM Ajax navigation enabled.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16519546/dont-hide-loader-till-the-page-loads-completely-in-jquery-mobile/16520313#16520313